# How to find time difference between previous and following rows from specific rows

Tags: r, dataframe, time, difference

I would like to calculate the difference in time for rows before and after a specific row if it satisfies a condition. I don't want to find the difference in sequence (row 3 - row 2, row 4 - row 3, etc.), but want the difference from the central row. Maybe another way to say it is distance from 0.

If the start column reads "y" I want that row's time to be the origin, but only for 5 seconds. I have about 600,000 rows of a roughly continuous time sequence, so calculating for 5 s on both sides of start should hopefully make it so the calculation doesn't overlap. I'm not even sure how this would look in code. Example data, many columns omitted for ease:

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          initiate = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
             start = c("no","no","yes","no","no",
                       "no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no"),
              time = c(2.8225,2.82375,2.825,2.82625,
                       2.827,2.82725,16.8075,16.810,16.82,16.8212,16.825,
                       16.8262,16.8275,16.8300)
)
```

| initiate | start | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | no | 2.8225 |
| 0 | no | 2.82375 |
| 1 | yes | 2.82500 |
| 1 | no | 2.82625 |
| 1 | no | 2.82700 |
| 1 | no | 2.82725 |
| 0 | no | 16.8075 |
| 0 | no | 16.8100 |
| 0 | no | 16.8200 |
| 1 | yes | 16.8212 |
| 1 | no | 16.8250 |
| 0 | no | 16.8262 |
| 1 | no | 16.8275 |
| 1 | no | 16.8300 |

What I want the output to be is:

| initiate | start | time | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | no | 2.8225 | -0.00250 |
| 0 | no | 2.82375 | -0.00125 |
| 1 | yes | 2.82500 | 0 |
| 1 | no | 2.82625 | 0.00125 |
| 1 | no | 2.82700 | 0.00200 |
| 1 | no | 2.82725 | 0.00225 |
| 0 | no | 16.8075 | -0.0137 |
| 0 | no | 16.8100 | -0.0112 |
| 0 | no | 16.8200 | -0.0012 |
| 1 | yes | 16.8212 | 0 |
| 1 | no | 16.8250 | 0.00380 |
| 0 | no | 16.8262 | 0.00500 |
| 1 | no | 16.8275 | 0.00630 |
| 1 | no | 16.8300 | 0.00880 |

I've tried using lag, diff with shift, and the following code. I haven't been able to get the calculations to restart from those yes rows. This is the closest I've been able to get, but it only calculates from the 1st yes.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id, grp = cumsum(lag(start, default = '') == 'yes')) %>% 
  mutate(diff = time - time[match('yes', trial_start)]) %>% 
  {. ->> df}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fuzzyjoin` might be useful here:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df_grp <- df %>% 
  filter(start == "yes") %>% 
  select(time) %>% 
  group_by(grp = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(begin = time - 5,
         end = time + 5)
```

First we create a data.frame of your initial values with `-5` and `+5` values:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
   time   grp begin   end
  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2.82     1 -2.17  7.82
2 16.8      2 11.8  21.8
```

Next we use a `fuzzy_join` to attach it to the original data.frame and calculate the differences:

```r
df %>% 
  fuzzy_left_join(df_grp, 
                  by = c("time" = "begin", "time" = "end"),
                  match_fun = list(`>`, `<`)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(diff = time.x - time.y) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 14 x 8
   initiate start time.x time.y   grp begin   end     diff
      <int> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        0 no      2.82   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82 -0.00250
 2        0 no      2.82   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82 -0.00125
 3        1 yes     2.82   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82  0      
 4        1 no      2.83   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82  0.00125
 5        1 no      2.83   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82  0.00200
 6        1 no      2.83   2.82     1 -2.17  7.82  0.00225
 7        0 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8  -0.0137 
 8        0 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8  -0.0112 
 9        0 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8  -0.00120
10        1 yes    16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8   0      
11        1 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8   0.00380
12        0 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8   0.00500
13        1 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8   0.00630
14        1 no     16.8   16.8      2 11.8  21.8   0.00880
```

Comment: The first time I ran this, it went smoothly. In re-running the code today, I'm seeing "*** recursive gc invocation" which I don't recall from yesterday. I simply could have missed it, as I walked away from my computer as this code ran. Like I originally mentioned, I have about 600,000 rows in this particular df. I've added a gc() command as recommended by other users. Does this surprise you, or do you have any other advice?